# Vlookup in sql,bring values to another table

Tags: sqlite

good day,
I have a 
T1 with columns "Customer_id,kind,class" And 
T2 "Customer_Id,class".
I need to do lookup in sql.
If value in column "t1.kind" is 3 ,then set value of column "t1.class" 'smt',
If value of "t1.customer_id" is in "t2.customer_id" then bring the value t2.class to the "t1.class"
Else set value "t1.class" to 3.
How can i do this ny updating column in table t1.
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Read about triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` expression in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
update t1
set class = case
  when kind = 3 then 'smt'
  else coalesce((select max(t2.class) from t2 where t2.customer_id = t1.customer_id), 3) 
end
```

I use `max(t2.class)` instead of `t2.class` just in case the subquery returns more than 1 row.